# Partial fraction decomposition trouble

Tags: partial-fractions

I'm trying to do a partial fraction expansion on
$$Y = n \cdot \frac{e^{-pt_{0}}}{(p+n)(p^2+\omega^2)}$$

which gives $A(p^2+\omega^2)+(Bp+C)(p+n) = 1$
which implies

$$A = -B$$
$$Bpn=0\rightarrow B=0\rightarrow A=0$$

which is incorrect. Any help with what I'm missing would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition

$$
A(p^2 + \omega^2) + (B p + C)(p + n ) = 1
$$

leads to the equations

\begin{eqnarray}
A + B &=& 0 \\
B n + C &=& 0 \\
A \omega^2 +  C n &=& 1
\end{eqnarray}

whose solution is

\begin{eqnarray}
A &=& \frac{1}{\omega^2 + n^2} = -B \\
C &=& \frac{n}{\omega^2 + n^2}  
\end{eqnarray}

So the fraction is

$$
Y = \frac{n e^{-pt_0}}{\omega^2 + n^2}\left[ \frac{1}{p + n} + \frac{n-p}{p^2 + \omega^2} \right]
$$

Comment: I completely forgot the Cp which make B=0... Dang thank you